# Issues with downloading a PDF after deploying Vue.js app

Tags: vue.js, pdf, aws-amplify

So I'm creating a Vue.js web app to act as my resume. On there, I want users to be able to actually download a copy of my resume, but I can't seem to get it working correctly. On my `Home.vue` page, I have:

```
<template>
  <div class="flex-grow overflow-auto max-h-screen w-full dark:text-gray-300">
    <div class="m-auto pt-4 lg:grid lg:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-rows-2 lg:gap-8">
      <div class="m-auto">
        <img class="rounded-md" alt="headshot" src="../assets/headshot.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="m-auto">
        <h2 class="text-2xl pl-2 py-4 text-center lg:text-left lg:text-8xl lg:px-8">Quick blurb</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="lg:col-span-2 mx-auto lg:h-8">
        <p class="text-base text-center lg:text-2xl">
          <a href="mailto:example@example.com">Email</a>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <a href="https://www.linkedin.com" target="_blank">LinkedIn</a>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <a href="https://github.com" target="_blank">GitHub</a>
          &nbsp;|&nbsp;
          <a href="my_resume.pdf" download>Resume</a>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>

export default {
  name: 'Home'
}
</script>
```

When I'm running it locally, I have no issue downloading it. When I run `yarn build` and run a server from `dist/`, I have no issue downloading it. It's only when I deploy it on AWS Amplify and test it from there do I run into the issue (basically acting like it can't find it). I've tried putting

```
<a href="/my_resume.pdf" download>Resume</a>
```

as well as

```
<a :href="`${publicPath}my_resume.pdf`" download>Resume</a>
....
data () {
  return {
    publicPath: process.env.BASE_URL
  }
}
```

to no avail. It's in the `public/` folder, along with the `index.html` and an icon that it has no issues accessing. I have no idea what the issue is.

Answer (score 1):

I dont know what version of vue you use and how did you configure your webpack, so i dont know if my solution is gonna work for you, but here i go:

1. Add assets folder to your public folder and add in it your pdf:
   [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2ZsqX.png)

2.to your source folder add file vue.config.js if its not already there: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udijb.png)

3. define assets as your assets folder in your vue.config.js:

```
module.export ={
  assetsDir: 'assets'
}
```

4. 

```
<a href="assets/my_resume.pdf" download>Resume</a>
```

here is the documantation: https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#assetsdir

Comment: Still getting the same issue. Whenever I download it and try to open it in Adobe, I get  

"Adobe Acrobat could not open 'my_resume.pdf' because it is either 
not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged (for example, it was sent as an email attachment and wasn't correctly decoded)."

Comment: Has there been any progress then? I mean before u couldnt find the pdf at all and now you download it damaged. Or is it still the same behaviour?

Comment: Same behavior. I just tried opening it in a text editor and it looks like it's actually downloading the index.html file for some reason.

Comment: my thought process on this one was that webpack on build damage the pdf. so my proposed solution was supposed to solve it by putting the pdf file to public folder which is not being procesed by webpack. if it dwonloads index.html, u can try to redirect to the pdf which should be in public/assests/my_resume.pdf. thats all i got honestly. good luck :)